# Correct way of redirecting IP Address in .htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am using shared hosting and was told that I can access my website with my IP address and username like this:

```
http://12.34.56.789/~username
```

I would like to redirect this URL for SEO purposes. I found the redirect IP Address code (below) in a tutorial. Is the RewriteCond below correct?
Should the RewriteCond use `12.34.56.789/~username`
instead of only `12\.34\.56\.789` ?
If the below is incorrect, can you show me the correct code as I am a beginner with htaccess stuff.

```
#Redirect IP Address
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^12\.34\.56\.789$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Comment: You can access it that way until you've pointed your domain name to their server, at which point you'll just access it using your domain.  This is a way to access your site before your domain has pointed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^12\.34\.56\.789$
RewriteRule ^~username/(.*)$ http://www.domainname.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The condition is correct, the "HTTP_HOST" is the hostname part (no paths) of the URL, so everything after the `://` and before the next `/`

Comment: Thanks Jon! Just for my understanding, the code in my post above is **incorrect** for IP Address URL that contains `~username` such as `http://12.34.56.789/~username` ?

Comment: @leko your rule would also redirect the `~username/` part of the URL